# Valid Oracle SQL receives "Unexpected Packet" error when run through VS Code

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-code

I was debugging a SQL query when I ran across a strange error. After some work we obtained the following minimal query to cause the bug.

```sql
select /** :'*/ dummy --'
from dual;
```

Running this in VS Code with the extension Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code (SQL and PLSQL) v21.5.0 results in the following error.

```
TTCExecuteSql:ReceiveExecuteResponse - Unexpected Packet received.
```

The query runs entirely fine in SQL Developer on the same databases. I have run this against multiple 19c databases, and one 12c database as well.

Any character in the comments of the query can be removed and the query will run correctly. Almost any character can be replaced with 'a' and the query will run as well--except for the space after the colon.

I can fix the error by removing parts of the offending query. Strangely enough, you can insert a lot of text within the comments and the error will persist. We originally found the error in a working query.

Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: "Why does this happen?" It looks like a bug. "how can it be fixed?" [Report it to Oracle on their forum](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/13021-development_tools?tags=oracle-developer-tools-for-vs-code)

Comment: @user The OP states in the question that they are using the "Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code" extension which is why I told them to go and report it on Oracle's forum for extensions (and even tagged the specific extension they are using in the link).

Comment: @MT0 I have submitted the report to Oracle. We'll see what happens from there! Thanks.

https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/valid-oracle-sql-receives-unexpected-packet-error-when-run-0776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug which is fixed in Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code version 21.7.1.

To be able to update to 21.7.1, upgrade Visual Studio Code to version 1.67.0 or later.

If you have disabled automatic extension updates, press F1 to open the Command Palette and enter the Check for Extension Updates command and click the Update... button which will appear in the list of installed extensions.